# What evidence is there for silicon based life forms

Tags: life

What evidence is there for silicon based life forms. In writing a hard science book is there much 'science' to support such a notion. Examples of other work would be good

Comment: I think the Alien in the movies Alien\Aliens\etc were silicon based?

Comment: None.  We've never encountered one and have only postulated their existence and if you look at [my answer to this other question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/109390/alternative-biological-oxidizer/109400#109400) you'll see how hard it is to even try to develop a biology with a replaced base chemical.  However, if you Google "silicon based life forms" there are a fair number of articles on the matter.

Comment: "What evidence is there for silicon based life forms" - have you Googled this? "Examples of other work would be good" - you should do your own research before coming here.

Comment: Go to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_types_of_biochemistry#Silicon_biochemistry), do not pass go, do not collect 200 dollars, send me 200 dollars ... :-)

Comment: What is Google? Haha, thanks for the helpful comments, not so much the one telling me to use Google. All comments validate me :-)

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding SleepyBoBos! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site and what is considered worldbuilding. Have fun!
You may also find the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we've discovered silicon based life forms yet, however the theory is sound... check this out... http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Microbrain

of course this may have been where you initially discovered it :p

Comment: Hello Andrew and Welcome to World Building, if you have the time i would recommend taking the tour for the website if you haven't already https://stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Amoeba A little tip to make typing such comments easier: There are so-called [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/352819) that allow you to easily point to each sites most important resources, such as `[tour]`, `[help]`, `[meta]`, `[chat]` or even  `[edit]`. Just in case you haven't come across magic links (they are a bit hidden, but immensely useful if you ask me).

Comment: @Secespitus This is the first time I've heard of magic links. I only wish they'd been mentioned earlier. Why do I think it might be a good idea if they were somewhere less hidden? Immensely useful, puts it mildly. I am grateful for you mentioning them.

Comment: @a4android Yeah, nobody seems to know about them. It took me a looooong time of always copying the links to the [tour] and [help] per hand before someone mentioned magic links somewhere so I am trying to leave a comment like the above whenever I see someone using normal links or for example a different writing for [help] (the text is automatic so it can be a good indicator). Great that it was helpful for you! I also think they should be more visible, I just don't know where. They don't fit in the [tour] for example.

Comment: @Secespitus, I found the magic links recently. So happy, wish they were mentioned in the tour or something. I'm still having trouble creating normal links like go [here] instead of the long URL. do we just use the same linking formatting that is auto-created when we write a question? I tried that recently and that didn't work (I could have made an error in writing it out. I'm not exactly computer coding savvy here :) ) I normally go to edit question to see what others have done, but can't do that with comments.

Comment: @EveryBitHelps You can write styled links like `[text to be displayed](link/to/wherever)` - be careful about spaces, they are allowed in the display text, but not between the brackets for example. It's the same as in questions/answers so you can check them out by clicking on the "edit" button of answers that use such markdown to see how it's done. The Sandbox community wiki uses it for example.

Comment: @Secespitus ah you see, I was still using the [here][1] format that you get in the question write-up :) thanks. this helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**[Diatoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatom)**

If you want evidence of some form of silicon structures in organisms then these are your best evidences for it. If you don't like it their is also a crap ton of papers and stuff on [hypothetical silicon chemistry in living things.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_types_of_biochemistry)

Comment: following your logic a chicken is a limestone based life form, since it uses limestone for the shell of its egg.